# Trying installing pandas but it's showing me the "Entry path not found"

Tags: python, pandas

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkwmf.png)Installing pandas but getting the following error in the screenshot.

conda install pandas

Comment: Add the screenshot please

Comment: Please provide details on how you installed it.

Comment: Apologies added screenshot. Please check